# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable(...).row is not a function

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatable and i want to remove the selected row when click on that row..

Here is code for datatabe

```
$('.data-table').dataTable({
  "aaSorting": [],
  "oLanguage": {"sSearch": ""},
  "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {}
});
```

And here is delete functionality...

```
<input type="button" class="btndel btn-primary btn btn-primary" onclick="                                                                  $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected');
if ($('.tab1').hasClass('active')) {
  var rows = $('.data-table').dataTable().row('.selected').remove().draw();
  var xSum = 0;
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName('pp');
  var itemCount = items.length;
  var total = 0;
  $('.pp').each(function () {
  var che = isNaN($(this).text());
  if (che == false) {
    xSum += parseFloat($(this).text());
  }
});
var value1 = xSum / parseInt(itemCount);
$('#avgsold').text(value1.toFixed(2));
}
if ($('.tab2').hasClass('active')) {}" value="Delete" />
```

But it gives error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable(...).row is not a function

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have implemented the library?

Comment: Yup i have implemented the datatable library...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following code instead:

```
$('.data-table').DataTable().row('.selected').remove().draw();
```

or

```
$('.data-table').dataTable().api().row('.selected').remove().draw();
```

When DataTables plugin was updated to 1.10, access to newer API methods (such as [`row()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29)) became available through `DataTable()` or `dataTable().api()`. Older API methods are still available via `dataTable()`.

See [API](http://datatables.net/reference/api/) for more information.